# invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'QImage'

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, mingw, qt-creator

This happens even on a **newly created** Qt Creator project. It's a Qt Widgets Application. When I try to compile it using the Qt 5.4.2 MinGW toolchain I get this error:

```
..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include/QtCore/qtypeinfo.h:178:31: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'QImage'
         isLarge = (sizeof(TYPE)>sizeof(void*)), \
                               ^
```

If I compile it using the other toolchain I have installed (Qt 5.4.2 VS2008), the same project **compiles without any errors**.

So I assume this is a problem with the configuration of the MinGW toolchain.

Full compiler output - http://pastebin.com/kUW6Ss6v.

Is this a problem with the MinGW toolchain, and how do I fix it?

**Edit:** I created a minimal example that reproduces the error:

```
#include <QImage>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

This fails under the MinGW toolchain with the same error, but compiles under the VS2008 toolchain.

Comment: did you `#include <QImage>`?

Comment: It's a newly created project. I didn't make any changes to it.

Comment: The compiler seems to confuse `QImage` and `QPixmap`, as it believes qimage.h:85 declares `QPixmap` instead of `QImage`. Maybe there is some global `#define QImage QPixmap` somewhere?

Comment: @KarstenKoop I created a minimal example, see my edit. It has only `#include <QImage>`, which causes the error. I don't know where QImage might be defined as QPixmap, I tried `#undef` for both QImage and QPixmap before the #include but it didn't help.

Comment: if QT has a mailing list or support forum that'd be a place to try

Comment: grep the headers for mention of QImage and QPixmap on the same ilne. another thing to check is that it's not finding bogus includes (you have a lot of include paths)

Comment: @sashoalm, can you tell, please, how did you install Qt or MinGW - manually or through Maintance Tool?

Comment: @someoneinthebox I installed it via the Maintenance Tool months ago, and it has worked fine until it suddenly stopped working a 1-2 weeks ago. The problem is I don't remember doing anything to cause that - I haven't touched the Maintenance Tool, haven't done any updates to Qt or Qt Creator.

Comment: @sashoalm, have you tried reinstall MinGW? And, if you try change `#include <QImage>` to `#include <QtGui/QImage>` is there any changes? Also, I read that there can be conflicts with compilation if you have Qt 4 and Qt 5 together.

Comment: @someoneinthebox `<QtGui/QImage>` didn't help, but I found something interesting - 5 files in `c:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtGui\` have a Date Modified timestamp of `05/18/2016`, while the newest of the rest are `06/08/2015`. And among them are `qpainter.h` and `qimage.h`. So something has overwritten those files with who knows what, and recently. I assume it's exactly when the builds started failing. Those are the files:
qimage.h
qbrush.h
qpixmap.h
qpainter.h

Comment: @someoneinthebox Actually the contents of qimage.h seem to have been overwritten with the contents of qpixmap.h. No wonder weirdness was happening. I replaced the 5 files with older version I found in `c:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\qtbase\src`, and now it compiles fine.

Comment: @someoneinthebox Hey, since you steered me in the right direction (by mentioning the headers), can you post it as an answer so I can award the bounty to you? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: @sashoalm, ok, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I asked you in comments - have you tried [reinstall MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.1/threads-posix/dwarf/i686-4.9.1-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v3-rev2.7z/download)? And, if you try change `#include <QImage>` to `#include <QtGui/QImage>` is there any changes? Also, I read that there can be conflicts with compilation if you have Qt 4 and Qt 5 together.

Comment: Putting it here so it's visible - something had overwritten 5 of the header files in `c:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtGui`, and it had replaced `qimage.h` with the contents of `qpixmap.h`. A just reverted those files but reinstall would have worked as well.